# Failover and offline reads in GlusterFS?

Tags: storage, failover, glusterfs

I have a cluster, where all machines have the daemon running and the clients mounted. As far as I understand, only the machine where I run `peer probe` becomes the host.

- If a client goes down:

  - the cluster keeps running in the other machines.
  - you cannot access the volume on the client that has gone down even though it has `backupvolfile-server=localhost`
  - the client will resynchronize after reconnecting.
- If the host goes down:

  - no machine can access the volume.

This makes me wonder:

- A) Is there a way for a client that is down to read the volume locally and maybe even write on it and have the rest of the pool catch up when it reconnects?
- B) Is there a way to have a client take on the role of the host when it goes down?

Everything I find online is either vague or old information. Maybe someone here can guide me. Thanks in advance.